# Format string with constant number of characters

Tags: rust

I want my string to be displayed with 4 characters like this: `"a"` -> `"a   "` when I do `format!("{}", "a")`.

I read the [format documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/), and tried several solutions like `{:<4}` but it didn't work.

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly your problem is. The format string you mentioned is correct if you want to space-pad your string. Are you using `format!` when you should be using `println!` by any chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [fjh says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287327/format-rust-string-on-constant-number-of-characters#comment52452471_32287327), this works:

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!("a   ", format!("{:<4}", 'a'));
    assert_eq!("a   ", format!("{:<4}", "a"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If encountering this when the String to be aligned is generated by an Display impl, the following worked for me:

```
use std::fmt;

pub struct DoesNotAlign {
    pub x: u32
}

pub struct DoesAlign {
    pub x: u32
}

impl fmt::Display for DoesNotAlign {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "~{}~", self.x)
    }
}
    
impl fmt::Display for DoesAlign {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let s = format!("~{}~", self.x);
        s.fmt(f)
    }
}
    
fn main() {
    println!("#{:<10}#", DoesNotAlign { x: 42 });
    println!("#{:<10}#", DoesAlign { x: 42 });
}
```

Prints the following:

```
#~42~#
#~42~      #
```

[Try this code in the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=81f68a1aae59eed896cc4ebc7885cda9).